# trigger onCreate on more fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate

I Have 10 fragments inside an activity. Each Fragment onCreate method is fired on the previous on the selected and on the following fragment during navigation. Each fragment contains on the onCreate method that in my code should asyncronous make a call to recover dates, but this way i cant start every one at the same time. Does it exits any method to trigger every onCreate method from an other fragment. I would not to manage this situation from the main activity for a question of modularity.

Simply I wana start the onCreta method of 10 fragments concurrently

this is a normal fragment type like just without the async call where i try to call the other fragment onCreate:

```
public class MainFragmentLDash1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "dash1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    MainFragmentLImp2 fragm = (MainFragmentLImp2)fm.findFragmentByTag("firstFragmentWrapperImp2");
    fragm.onCreate(null);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dash1, container, false);


        return v;
    }


    public static MainFragmentLDash1 init(int position) {

        MainFragmentLDash1 f = new MainFragmentLDash1();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("msg", position);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

this way it crashes

Answer (score 0):

onCreate() is not designed for being called by you. It is triggered by the system when is needed, besides, onCreate() is automatically called when a fragment is instantiated and attached to an activity, so, your call is unnecessary.

You should put the actions you want to perform in a separated method and only call that method "concurrently" when you are sure that all your fragments have been created.

You can start by reading the fragments life-cycle documentation at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: so I should find a callback that manage the creation of a fragment. Because the simple check !=null may return false and overcome the trigger of that function

Comment: Normally, each fragment is responsible for its own job. Maybe if you add the "async" logic of your code, your situation will be more clear and better answers will appear.

Answer (score 0):

mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);